# Do Windows apps support SIGINT for user-defined signal handlers?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, signals, ipc

The [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=vs-2019#remarks) say:

> SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application. When a CTRL+C interrupt occurs, Win32 operating systems generate a new thread to specifically handle that interrupt. This can cause a single-thread application, such as one in UNIX, to become multithreaded and cause unexpected behavior.

I think it means by default, the `SIG_DFL` handler for `SIGINT` will create a new thread, handle the signal then terminate the program. I'd like to know, does Windows support user-defined `SIGINT` handler, or will the handler ignored by the OS and the default `SIG_DFL` handler will run if a CTRL+C interrupt occurs?

For example, will the following code print `Signaled!`?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t signaled = 0;
void signal_handler(int) { signaled = 1; }

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    while (!signaled) {}
    printf("Signaled!\n");
}
```

Comment: "For example, do the following code print Signaled!?" - If you tried it you would know.

Comment: On Windows you should be using `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` instead.

Comment: @BenVoigt If possible, I'd like to use os-agnostic feature, `signal` is supported by the MSVC compiler so I'll try it first before checking `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: Signals aren't OS-agnostic. They require a POSIX-compliant OS. Some OS' are, Windows isn't quite.

Comment: @IInspectable afaik Windows implemented POSIX.1 standard decades ago, which means the OS is POSIX-compliant and should support signals just fine. Am I incorrect?

Comment: Windows implemented POSIX.1 (Interix) so that Microsoft could sign deals with US Government agencies. It **was** POSIX.1 compliant at one point in time. Interix was later replaced by SFU, which was later replaced by SUA, which was later deprecated with Windows 8 and removed with Windows 8.1. Though I don't know what the POSIX-compliance story is today with WSL around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Win32 does fire `SIGINT` on Ctrl-C, with a couple of caveats:

- it is fired from another thread,
- it needs to be re-armed after each hit.

The second bullet introduces a race condition, and so it might be better to use the Win32 native [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler?redirectedfrom=MSDN) instead.

Comment: When you said it was fired from another thread, is it the new thread created by the Windows OS?

Comment: @b1105029 _"...SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application...."_ and _"...Win32 operating systems generate a new thread to specifically handle that interrupt...."_ source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=vs-2019